# How to use try catch error for sql query timeout?

Tags: c#, sql, try-catch

How can i use try catch if there is an error in the connection to the sql query in c#?

If I use the simple code below it does work but the time it takes for an error to occur is too long. How can I get the try catch to handle the error quicker?

```
try
{
  //sql command
}
catch
{
  //display connection error
}
```

Comment: Seems that your command timeout is too long. It may be interesting if you are using ADO.NET, EF, Linq2SQL, or whatever?

Comment: use "throw new Exception()" to have a lightning fast exception thrown. J/K

Comment: If the error you're worried about is a timeout, then by definition you can't get it to handle faster - the whole point of a timeout is that it's taken too long. If you think it takes too long to decide that it's timed out, reduce the timeout limit on your database connection.

Comment: More seriously you can't do what you're asking. See what your errors are and try to find ways to detect issues before they occur.

Comment: You might also want to run your query inside another thread (Task) and using a Semaphore (for instance) to wait a certain time for the query to run until while letting the query continue running, you consider a time out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`try-catch` will catch the exception as soon as it occurs, but don't expect to catch a timeout exception *before* the timeout occurs. For `SqlCommand`, the default timeout is **30 seconds**, but you can change it by setting the `CommandTimeout` property:

```
try
{ 
    var command = new SqlCommand("...");
    command.CommandTimeout = 5; // 5 seconds
    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
catch(SqlException ex)
{
    // handle the exception...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't catch an exception until it occurs.  If you want to catch it sooner, cause it to happen sooner.  Specifically, shorten the timeout period.

I know how to reduce the timeout period in ColdFusion.  I'd have to look at [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.commandtimeout.aspx) to see how to do it in .net.

Answer (score 0):

**Do by following way:**

```
try
{
  con.open();
  .
  .//Database operation
  .
  con.close();
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
  MessageBox.Show("Error: "+ex.Message);//If exception will come, it will handle it here.
}
finally
{
 con.close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
catch (SqlException ex)
    {
        if (ex.Number == -2)
        {
            //handle timeout
        }        
    }
```

Comment: Try to give an explanation as opposed to just a snippet of code.